# Magento 2.4 overwrite tier_prices.phtml

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I'm trying to overwrite tier_prices.phtml file.

1. mkdir -p app/design/frontend/Vendor/Namespace/Magento_Catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/
2. nano app/design/frontend/Vendor/Namespace/registration.php

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

use \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::THEME, 'frontend/Vendor/Namespace', __DIR__);
```

3. nano app/design/frontend/Vendor/Namespace/theme.xml

```
     Custom Tier Prices
     Magento/luma
```

4. nano app/design/frontend/Vendor/Namespace/Magento_Catalog/view/base/templates/product/price /tier_prices.phtml

tier_prices.phtml is original file copied from vendor folder with my editing.

5. rm -rf pub/static/* generated/* var/view_preprocessed/*
6. php bin/magento setup:di:compile
7. php bin/magento setup:di:static-content:deploy -f
8. Check from admin>content>configuration>design configuration of my view -> set my custom theme

SAVE

nothing works!!! Why?
I try to change Magento_Catalog with Magento_ConfigurableProduct but it's not work.

Thanks for any answer

Answer (score 0):

To override phtml files there are two methods

1- Copy it in your custom theme
app/design/themeX/themeY/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/tier_prices.phtml

2- Create custom module and override phtml file

```
app/code/Filippo/Catalog/etc/module.xml
app/code/Filippo/Catalog/registration.php
app/code/Filippo/Catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/price/tier_prices.phtml
```

Enable the module and refresh cache

```
bin/magento module:enable Filippo_Catalog
bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. These methods don't work

Comment: check if the same file are not overrided else where or you have a capital letter error
flush magento cache
flush varnish cache
check that you are on developer mode

Answer (score 0):

The path of the template is wrong

Put your code in: app/design/themeX/themeY/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/tier_prices.phtml

Clear cache and recheck

Comment: Hi, thanks. With your path it doesn't work. Any other suggestions?